# Autolayout constraints between two dynamically resizing views

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, interface-builder

**Premise**

I have a superview C that simply contains two subviews A and B. ASCII art:

```
+-----------+
|   view A  |
|   view B  |
+-----------+
```

Here's what I want:

- A's top must be pinned to C's top. A's height is not pinned to anything; it actually changes depending on its contents: it's a scrollview-less `NSTextView`.
- B's top must always be 10 pixels from A's bottom. B's bottom must always be pinned to C's bottom.

The entire view C should be split between A and B, and the division between A and B must be decided by A's current height (which is decided by `NSTextView`), and B should fill any remaining space not taken by A.

*In other words*: A stays at the top. B fills out the rest of the superview. As A grows, B is pushed downwards.

**The problem**

Interface Builder always creates undeletable constraint that pins B's top to C's top. This means that B will always be positioned at a specific Y position. If I give B a height constraint, this doesn't happen, but that is not what I want.

[image: Interface Builder]

I have tried implementing the superview's `updateConstraints` to delete this IB-generated constraint. That sort of works but when I do this, B's top is never adjusted and seems to be set arbitrarily. It doesn't matter what I set the constraint priority to, B ends up positioned either at the bottom of C, or at the top, or somewhere far off screen. Also, A seems to grow to fill the entirety of C.

Here is the auto-created constraint I can't get rid of:

[image: Interface Builder]

**Additional details**

I should add that C is a cell view in a view-based `NSTableView`. I calculate the required height to fit A and B in `tableView:heightOfRow`, and expect the contraints to lay everything out.

Comment: Have you tried pinning the bottom of B to C then pin the vertical spacing between A and B.  With the one constraint you have on the right had side, you should then be able to delete the constraint that is connected from B to the top of C.

Comment: B's bottom space is already pinned to C, and the spacing between A and B are already pinned. In the screenshot I had apparently played with editing the top-constraint, so it's a bit off; I have edited to add another screenshot focusing on the auto-created constraint, which has top-to-superview equals 46, with a purple icon indicating it's automatically created and not deletable.

Comment: how about reducing the priority of the b-top constraint?

Comment: Once you have enough constraints to satisfy auto layout, you should be able to delete something.  Try selecting the whole view and then select the size inspector.  You should see all the constraints listed in there.  Then find your top to superview constraint in the boxes, select it and promote to user constraint.  You should then be able to delete it.

Comment: To go along with danh, after reducing the priority, if you can't delete with my other suggestion, try making that one greater or equal to.

Comment: As I wrote above, changing the priority does nothing. And if I change the "equal" to "greater than or equal to", then IB just adds an identical, non-deletable "equal" constraint like the one I tried to change: [Before](http://i.imgur.com/ipJ2pDG.png), [after](http://i.imgur.com/ipJ2pDG.png).

Comment: If I change the priority, the constraint becomes deletable. If I then delete it, it's added again (as non-deletable).

Comment: [Here](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/12091499/Share/layoutproblem.zip) is a test project reducing the problem to a very simple view. Also notice how resizing the window vertically makes the views jump around erratically.

Comment: Wow, I am stumped.  I have tried all sorts of things.  Have you tried to do it programmatically? With something like NSLayoutConstraint *myConstraint = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:[textView]-10-[textCell]" options:0 metrics:nil];  But you would need to synthesize the textCell.  And I am not sure what to put for the views part.  Keep us posted.  I would love to find out the true answer.

Comment: I haven't, but I *have* confirmed that the generated constraints are sound. Actually I have given up trying to make it behave automatically, and instead I have set the height explicitly for both views (to dummy values), connected the constraints to outlets, and I then call `constraint.constant = someHeight;` to set the height. In my case the heights of both views are derived from their content, so it works, even if it's less than ideal.

Comment: It's no mystery why you can't do this the way you're trying because there's no way for the system to know how to apportion the height between the two views if they're both flexible. You shouldn't have to fix the height of both views though -- just set A's height to any arbitrary value in IB, and change it to what you want in heightOfRow: (with constraint.constant like you're doing), B should follow along.

Comment: Excellent point, @rdelmar. However, if view A has an `intrinsicContentSize`, the layout system should be able to derive its "ideal height" and use that. Possibly this is what will happen if you construct the constraints programmatically, I haven't tried; but IB won't do it. (Although from my previous experiences with `intrinsicContentSize`, I doubt it will actually work.)

Comment: Yeah, I think that's just the way intrinsic content size works with a text view -- in IB, when you set that, it gives it a fixed size, something it doesn't do for buttons or switches.

Comment: Here's an interesting follow-up (re your recommendation, @rdelmar): It turns out that I *can't* have a spacing constraint between A and B. Seems I have touched on a bug in `NSTableView`. It's a view-based table, and whenever the table reused a cell view the contents suddenly became erratic (blank, wrongly positioned, etc.). I reduced my case down to the barest minimum, and it's definitely the constraints getting confused. So I have ended up with *two* constant-programmed constraints: One for the height of A, and one of the top of B. I set the top of B to be the height of A + some space.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for posterity: Having a configuration like a described is apparently not possible with constraints. My solution so far, which works:

- Create a constraint on A that sets a specific height. (In IB, I set a dummy height.)
- Create a constraint on B that sets a specific top.
- *Don't* specify a vertical spacing between A and B. (At least in my case this triggered weird behaviour in `NSTableView`.)
- In your controller or view code, compute out A's height and set it using the `constraint.constant` property.
- Also in your controller or view code, compute out B's top (using A's height) and set it using the `constraint.constant` property.